# C# Get all combinations (for card game)

Tags: c#, get, combinations

I'm creating a card game on C# with Windows.Forms GUI. I don't know the name of the game, but the rule is this:

(For example you have the card 10 in hand)
If on the table is another 10, or a couple of cards which sum is equal to 10 (2, 3 and 5 ; 7 and 3 or etc. ) you get that cards with the card from your hand.

!This only use the number cards and the Ace that is equal to 1.

The problem is that i don't know the number of the cards of the table; it's changeable. How can i make for loop (or something else) who add all possible combinations with the cards on the table (as string) to ListBox?

I have a string array with all cards on the table (example):

tableCards[0] = "2_of_clubs"
tableCards[1] = "ace_of_diamonds"
...

For output i only need ListBox or another array, called cardsToGet with all possible compinations (as string):

Example for 10 in hand and 5, 7, 2 and 3 on the table:
cardsToGet[0] - "5_of_clubs and 2_of_diamonds and 3_of_hearts"
cardsToGet[1] - "7_of_hearts and 3_of_diamonds"
...

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail to your post. Things to include: what you've tried, what didn't work, your code that isn't working, an accurate description of what you expect the result/output to be, etc.

Comment: Ok I have added more accurate description now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets use this data structure for table state:

```
//Ace, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7
int[] table = new int[10] { 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 };
```

The result combination can consist of zero or one Ace, zero or one 2, zero or one or two or three 3, no 4 and so on. You can iterate over all combinations via ten nested for loops. Or You can use recursion. You can break loop (or return from recursive function) when partial sum is already bigger than desired value to speed it up. If You get stuck with the code, feel free to ask again (with concrete code).